# find all characters NOT in regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a regex of legal characters

```
legals = re.compile("[abc]")
```

I can return a list of legal characters in a string like this:

```
finder = re.finditer(legals, "abcdefg")
[match.group() for match in finder]
>>>['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How can I use regex to find a list of the characters NOT in the regex? IE in my case it would return

```
['d','e','f','g']
```

Edit: To clarify, I'm hoping to find a way to do this without modifying the regex itself.

Comment: Almost certainly an inefficient solution, but you could generate the list of legal chars and subtract that list from the list of all the chars

Answer (score 6):

Negate the character class:

```
>>> illegals = re.compile("[^abc]")
>>> finder = re.finditer(illegals, "abcdefg")
>>> [match.group() for match in finder]
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

If you can't do that (and you're only dealing with one-character length matches), you could

```
>>> legals = re.compile("[abc]")
>>> remains = legals.sub("", "abcdefg")
>>> [char for char in remains]
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: What if he doesn't know the regexp, i.e. he only has `legals` variable?

Comment: I think the question is if it's possible to do without changing the regex itself.

Comment: I'm hoping to find a way to do this without altering the character class itself. Like I'm wondering if there's a module or parameter that will allow this.

Comment: @subyraman: Then just remove all the matches from the string and see what remains. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @freakish: You mean something like `[c for c in "abcdefg" if not legals.match(c)]`?

Comment: @Tadeck Yeah, quite inefficient though. The same goes for Tim's solution (a bit better). But I guess that this is probably the best we can do.